# How to get Innodb_rows_inserted and Innodb_rows_deleted values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, innodb

In Mysql I am getting Innodb_rows_inserted and Innodb_rows_deleted values using these queries

select variable from information_schema.global_status where variable_name = 'innodb_rows_inserted'

Same thing I want to achieve in postgresql. Innodb is not used in postgres so I want to get some queries to fetch total inserted and deleted rows count .Can anyone help me how to get Innodb_rows_inserted  and Innodb_rows_deleted values in postgresql. Thanks in advance

Comment: Postgres doesn't use InnoDB, but it does have an [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/information-schema.html) so have a look around there.

Comment: @tadman yeah we are not using innodb in postgres. I want similar queries in postgres to get inserted and deleted values. I am using these values to monitor database

Comment: I don't know what they map to, but I do know that if those values are there, you'll find them in that documentation.

Comment: Most probably [pg_stat_all_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW)